# Google Play Game Services disconnects when app minimized or display off?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm using the "google play game services plugin for unity" for a multiplayer game. When I close/open the android device screen or minimize/maximize the app or click on an ad banner which opens the browser and pauses my app, I'm disconnected from the google play services.

How can I make it, that the google play games services not disconnect?

I disconnect the user in the game. So why it's disconnecting self?

The main problem here is, that I can't show any ad banners anymore. Because the user is kicked when he clicks on the banner. I mean, click on an ad banner opens the browser. My app is then minimized and google play services is disconnected.

Comment: Please provide the code where you implement the Play Game Service and maybe weher you override the onStop(), onPause() methods of your Activity

Comment: I don't have onStop(), onPause() etc. I'm using: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity | So I can't change anything in the onStop() etc.

Comment: Maybe @BrunoOliveira can give us some tips.